# How to get a element position (left or right) relative to the screen?

Tags: html, jquery, css, masonry

I'm using a masonry type layout on my web page and I need to style every element that appears on the right side of the screen in a different than the other ones. This is the reference that I used for the  [masonry](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/#order-shifted-elements-in-a-flexbox-layout). At first, I need the right side elements to float right and have different margin settings, and since the height in my project variants a lot, sometimes the elements going left or right dot not alternate in the same way every time.
I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and JQuery 3.4.1.
This is my code:

```js
function checkContainer() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        return 585;
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        return 485;
    }
    return $('.container').width();
}

var minColWidth = checkContainer();
var roots;

function onLoad() {
    var rootElements = document.getElementsByClassName('masonry-root');
    roots = Array.prototype.map.call(rootElements, function (rootElement) {
        var cellElements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName('masonry-cell');
        var cells = Array.prototype.map.call(cellElements, function (cellElement) {
            var style = getComputedStyle(cellElement);
            return {
                'element': cellElement,
                'outerHeight': parseInt(style.marginTop) + cellElement.offsetHeight + parseInt(style.marginBottom)
            };
        });
        return {
            'element': rootElement,
            'noOfColumns': 0,
            'cells': cells
        };
    });

    // do the first layout
    onResize();
}

function onResize() {
    for (let root of roots) {

        // only layout when the number of columns has changed
        var newNoOfColumns = Math.floor(root.element.offsetWidth / minColWidth);
        if (newNoOfColumns != root.noOfColumns) {

            // initialize
            root.noOfColumns = newNoOfColumns;
            var columns = Array.from(new Array(root.noOfColumns)).map(function (column) {
                return {
                    'cells': new Array(),
                    'outerHeight': 0
                };
            });

            // divide...
            for (let cell of root.cells) {
                var minOuterHeight = Math.min(...columns.map(function (column) {
                    return column.outerHeight;
                }));
                var column = columns.find(function (column) {
                    return column.outerHeight == minOuterHeight;
                });
                column.cells.push(cell);
                column.outerHeight += cell.outerHeight;
            }

            // calculate masonry height
            var masonryHeight = Math.max(...columns.map(function (column) {
                return column.outerHeight;
            }));

            // ...and conquer
            var order = 0;
            for (let column of columns) {
                for (let cell of column.cells) {
                    cell.element.style.order = order++;
                    // set the cell's flex-basis to 0
                    cell.element.style.flexBasis = 0;
                }
                // set flex-basis of the last cell to fill the
                // leftover space at the bottom of the column
                // to prevent the first cell of the next column
                // to be rendered at the bottom of this column
                column.cells[column.cells.length - 1].element.style.flexBasis = column.cells[column.cells.length - 1].element.offsetHeight + masonryHeight - column.outerHeight - 1 + 'px';
            }

            // set the masonry height to trigger
            // re-rendering of all cells over columns
            // one pixel more than the tallest column
            root.element.style.maxHeight = masonryHeight + 1 + 'px';

            console.log(columns.map(function (column) {
                return column.outerHeight;
            }));
            console.log(root.element.style.maxHeight);
        }
    }
}

// subscribe to load and resize events
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
```

```css
.masonry-root {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.masonry-root .masonry-cell {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 4px;
}
.masonry-root .masonry-cell .masonry-item {
    height: auto;
}
.feed-content {
    width: 450px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry-root">
    <div class="masonry-cell">
        <div class="masonry-item">
            <div class="feed-content">
            <!-- html content like images and text -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="masonry-cell">
        <div class="masonry-item">
            <div class="feed-content">
            <!-- html content like images and text -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the left position of the element using CSS but didn't work out. The same thing happened when jquery .position() or offsetLeft() were used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some stuff here and found something that worked.

```
// puting all the elements that I'm going to use in a list 
var feeds = document.querySelectorAll('.feed-content');
// since I know that, im a 2 columns grid the first element 
// will alaways be on the right side off the screen I get
// his x position
var dir = feeds[0].getBoundingClientRect().x;

for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
    feeds[i].classList.remove('right');

    if (feeds[i].getBoundingClientRect().x != dir) {
        // adding the cllas if the element doesn't 
        // have that x position
        feeds[i].classList.add('right');
    }
}
```

Some advice, when I was working with the plugin used on the question sometimes this function had a bug that made all elements on the page trow the same x value, even if clearly they weren't the same. Even if this part of the code was put after the script functions of the layout it way some interference. So simply delaying the function execution fixed the problem.